# In the middle of cooking, someone realises the pot they are using was previously used for non kosher food

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, utensil

If someone accidentally starts to cook kosher food in a pot that was used to cook non-kosher food, but the pot wasn't used in 24 hours, may the person let the food finish cooking?

Answer (score 1):

It is forbidden to cook in a pot once you know it is non-kosher but, after the fact, one can eat the food. The Shulchan Aruch ([YD 122:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.122.2?lang=bi&with=Halakhah&lang2=en)) writes (Sefaria's translation with my slight adjustments)

> A vessel which is not *ben yomo*, meaning that the vessel has sat for 24
> hours since prohibited substance was cooked in it, this gives a
> detrimental taste, but even so, the Sages forbade cooking in it
> initially.

In this specific case, I asked R Binyamin Tabady who said that, once one realizes the pot is non-kosher, one should pour the food in another pot and can eat the food (and need to *kasher* the original pot). If one did not pour the food in another vessel, after the fact, one can still eat the food.

For a broader discussion of these issues see [here](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/noten-taam-lifgam-what-if-one-accidentally-cooked-food-non-kosher-pot) (and the conclusion under "Natlap Be-Keilim – In Practice")

Of course, as usual, don't trust anything you read here, and ask your Rav should this happen in real life.